# parse string to vector of int

Tags: c++, stdvector, stdstring

I have a string which contains some number of integers which are delimited with spaces. For example

```
string myString = "10 15 20 23";
```

I want to convert it to a vector of integers. So in the example the vector should be equal

```
vector<int> myNumbers = {10, 15, 20, 23};
```

How can I do it? Sorry for stupid question.

Comment: Use `boost::split_regex`

Comment: @juanchopanza Could you kindly explain how splitting into **strings** is considered the same as splitting into a ***vector of int***?

Comment: @jrok There are significant differences between mere splitting a string and splitting a string while simultaneously converting type.

Comment: @Shafik_Yaghmour I get that that there's a strong overlap - but those that's most certainly not a duplicate.

Comment: @Christopher_Creutzig Not a single answer on the **alleged** duplicate question returns a ***vector of int***.

Comment: @Mario_Sannum If there is a ***genuine*** duplicate of this question, then by all means mark it so. However, it is completely unhelpful to reference a similar, but ***clearly not*** duplicate question.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use `std::stringstream`. You will need to `#include <sstream>` apart from other includes.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

std::string myString = "10 15 20 23";
std::stringstream iss( myString );

int number;
std::vector<int> myNumbers;
while ( iss >> number )
  myNumbers.push_back( number );
```

Comment: I think adding also the include statements will make this answer even better.

Comment: I mean all (+vector) - and also the [using declarations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration) necessary to make it compile. I'll keep my (+1) ready :)

Comment: ...BTW: **I love this** `while (iss >> number)` :-)

Comment: Great! (+1d) Another alternative was `using std::vector; using std::stringstream; using std::string;`

Answer (score 12):

```
std::string myString = "10 15 20 23";
std::istringstream is( myString );
std::vector<int> myNumbers( ( std::istream_iterator<int>( is ) ), ( std::istream_iterator<int>() ) );
```

Or instead of the last line if the vector was already defined then

```
myNumbers.assign( std::istream_iterator<int>( is ), std::istream_iterator<int>() );
```

Comment: It would be more correctly to write the last line as std::vector<int> myNumbers( ( std::istream_iterator<int>( is ) ), std::istream_iterator<int>() ); that is to enclose the first argument in parentheses. Otherwise instead of the vector definition it will be a function declaration.:)

Comment: Or you could use initializer list construct that is designed to solve that problem. `std::vector<int> myNumbers{ std::istream_iterator<int>( is ), std::istream_iterator<int>() };`

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty much a duplicate of the other answer now.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::string s = "1 2 3 4 5";
    std::istringstream iss(s);
    std::vector<int> v{std::istream_iterator<int>(iss),
                       std::istream_iterator<int>()};
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
}
```

Comment: No need to use `std::copy`. Because `std::vector` has a constructor that takes two iterators (just like std::copy).

Comment: Also the the *good old for loop* for output should better be not included here, because it's *not easy*.