# How do I split a string and store each number in a vector of integers?

Tags: c++, string, vector, split

I have an input string of integers separated by space.

```
string input = "116 119 220 250";
```

How do I split this string and store each number in vector of integers?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Right way to split an std::string into a vector<string>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607589/right-way-to-split-an-stdstring-into-a-vectorstring)

Comment: Look that [Parse string to vector of int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20659066/parse-string-to-vector-of-int)